# ubuntu error installation in SONY VAIO model VGN-T330FP

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

When I try to install any version of Ubuntu I initially load the ubuntu screen, but then the screen goes black. Please somebody help me

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like video drivers to me.

Maybe try the [command line based installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems) and then add a windows manager of your choice afterwards like XFCE?

Comment: A friend told me that I pass and look and had to press a number key and then but I'm still hunting for keys